# CRUD REST API - Who "creates" the C# obejct itself?

Tags: c#, wcf, crud

I have a WCF-based, C# CRUD REST api that works on Schedule objects.  There are methods for creating, updating, deleting as you'd expect.

My problem is that the Schedule object contains a TriggerInfo subobject.  If you just call the constructor, you're really calling the constructor of a proxy, and the real constructor is never called, so the subobjects are not initialized.

The proxy that WCF emits has TriggerInfo as a field but it's always going to be null because the constructor logic in the "real" class is never called.

In other words, when the client creates a C# 'Schedule' object, it's really creating a proxy of the real Schedule class, and the proxy knows nothing about having to init anything!

So in this chicken-and-egg situation, who creates the C# 'Schedule' object that the client can "fill out"?

I thought the C# client could create a Schedule object, fill out all the properties and pass it to the CreateSchedule() api and it'd work.  Not so easy!

It'd work if I made a big, flat monolithic class where all of the TriggerInfo properties were properties on the Schedule object instead, but it's not very tidy, especially if you have multiple subclasses.

I could have a ScheduleFactory object exposed on my API that knows how to create one, but I don't know if that's a valid approach!

Answer (score 1):

Don't create Schedule object client-side if it needs any nontrivial initialization - just add a *New* or *Create* method to your WCF service and do it server-side. Alternatively, you can use *new Schedule()* client-side, get a new proxy instance with a lot of null properties and fill in these properties with sensible default values server-side in *Save* method.

Comment: I added a CreateSchedule() call to the service API which returns an empty schedule properly initialized.  That seems to work.  

However, should the caller pass the unique ID to the Create call?  Like if my Schedule name is the unique value, should it specify one for the create call?  Or should the returned object be totally empty and then you have to fill out the unique ID and do an Update afterwards?